# How can I write a small feature in react JS and integrating it with both IOS and android app?

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

Is it a good idea to write a small feature in reactJS for both IOS/Android to save the development time? If so, what are the best practices for doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React Native is definitely made to save development time when writing iOS & Android apps. Most of your code will run perfectly on both platforms without any optimisation required. If you want the exact same experience on both platform, you should simply stay away from platform specific components like `<ToolbarAndroid />` or `<TabBarIOS />` for example. Also, when using third party libraries, make sure they work on both platforms.

If you need to customize the experience for iOS or Android, writing separate features is as easy as splitting your component as `myComponent.ios.js` and `myComponent.android.js` and the framework will pick the correct file at build time.

See the documentation on [Platform Specific Code](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/platform-specific-code.html) for more details.